# Univariate drought return period calculation, missing a step?

Tags: r, probability, predictive-models

I am calculating univariate drought return period calculations using the methodology from (Shiau and Shen 2001, Shiau 2006). To make sure that I’m doing it correctly, I am recreating their calculations before performing them on my own data.

According to the methodology, the steps are as follows:

1. Fit univariate drought characteristic distributions. The example I’m using is drought duration fitted to an exponential distribution with lambda = 1.529.
2. This is used, along with estimated drought inter-arrival time $E(L)$ to calculate the equation for return period:

$TD= \frac{E(L)}{1-FD(d)}$

Where $TD$ is the return period for drought duration; $E(L)$ is the estimated inter-arrival time, here it is 4.337 months; and $FD(d)$ is the cumulative distribution function for drought duration.

The results calculated are:

```
Return period (years)   Duration (months)
   2                    2.62
   5                    4.02
  10                    5.08
  20                    6.14
  50                    7.54
 100                    8.6
```

To recreate the analysis, I plugged in the exponential CDF into the equation above and solved for $x$, then plugged other variables in to solve for the duration for each return period and did not get answers that were even close, making me think that I’m missing a step somewhere. My R code is below, any advice is greatly appreciated.

‘Solution’ for x:

$x= \frac{\ln\left(\frac{L}{R}\right)+1}{-\lambda}$

R code (clearly something has gone terribly wrong):

```
df<-data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 6, ncol = 2))
names(df)<-c("Return","D")
df$Return<-c(2,5,10,20,50,100)
df$D<-c(2.62,4.02,5.08,6.14,7.54,8.6)
L<-4.337
lambda<-1.529

df$new<-(log(L/df$Return)+1)/-lambda
```

Refs:

Shiau, J. T. 2006. Fitting drought duration and severity with two-dimensional copulas. *Water Resources Management*. 20:795–815.

Shiau, J. T., and H. W. Shen. 2001. Recurrence analysis of hydrologic droughts of differing severity. *Journal of Water Resources Planning and Management*. 127:30–40.

Comment: In your formula there is an a not otherwise explained. Why are you using common logs rather than natural logs?

Comment: My apologies, both of those were typos.  There is no variable 'a' and I am using natural logs.

Comment: Can u share your procedure for drought inter-arrival time E(L) calculation?

Comment: Brother hwo would you calculate the interarrival time If you have any formula please share with me. Thank you